# Direct replacement within a function body of arguments such as the symbols >, <, !=, ==

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Let' s suppose I call a function  with the  Greater symbol ">" an argument:

```
findb[x^2 - 10, ">", 0]
```

Instead of testing within the function body what the second argument is (the usual design) I want  it to replace directly every expression where it appears:

```
findb[exp_Plus, ptest_String, value_?NumberQ] := 
Module[{}, 
x /. Flatten[{FindInstance[(exp ToExpression[ptest]  value) &&  
   x  != 0 , x, Reals]}]]
```

As this cannot work with the `ToExpression` built-in what is the way to achieve this result?

Comment: work with `ToString` construct the whole expression as a string and feed that to `ToExpression`.  Suggest you take this sort of question to mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As hinted by @agentp here is an answer which is OK:

```
  findb[exp_Plus, ptest_String, value_?NumberQ] := Module[{},
   x /.Flatten[{FindInstance[(ToExpression[
   StringJoin[ToString[exp, InputForm], ptest, 
   ToString[value]]]) &&  x  != 0 , x, Reals]}]]
```

However I find that very verbose. Can it be improved?

Comment: minor improvent: `ToString` can be applied to the string, so you can write this more compactly as `ToExpression@StringJoin[ToString /@ {exp, ptest, value}]`

Answer (score 0):

Alternate approach, assuming you support a discrete list of allowable operators:

```
 Switch[ ptest ,
          ">" , exp > value ,
          "<" , exp < value , ... ]
```

not elegant, but it may be the safest most robust approach.